# Reduce the speed of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone have a look at this and help me find a way to reduce the speed of the text that scrolls in and scrolls out? I cannot seem to figure out these codes, that's why, need your expert input.

Really appreciate your help

Here is the vs

```
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
        this.toRotate = toRotate;
        this.el = el;
        this.loopNum = 0;
        this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
        this.txt = '';
        this.tick();
        this.isDeleting = false;
    };

    TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
        var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
        var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

        if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
        } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
        }

        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

        var that = this;
        var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

        if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

        if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
        } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
        }, delta);
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
            var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
            if (toRotate) {
              new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
            }
        }
        // INJECT CSS
        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { top:200%; border-right: 0.08em solid #fff; color:#F68703; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 2px 4px #000}";
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    };
```

Comment: increase `delta`

Comment: ...and `delta` is driven, in part, by the `period` constructor parameter.

Comment: @JaromandaX u mean the delta = 500?

Comment: I tried increasing it takes no effect the scroll speed remains same

Comment: oh i got it delta 200

Comment: no, that's not the one ... `var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;` try increasing the 200 - you beat me to it